# Explicitly throwing the exception in java in method calls

Tags: java, exception

I have the below method in which the last parameter I want to throw the exception with my custom error message , I am doing it by the following way as shown below..

```
String errorMessage = errorMessageServiceHome.getErrorMessage(avc.Constants.COR_TET); 
abcnHelper.def(aaa, null, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, rrr, new Throwable(errorMessage));
```

please advise am I doing it rite way..!!

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Was it what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

[Throwing an exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) is done by simply using the throw keyword:

```
public void someMethod()
{
    if(something)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        throw new SomeException("My Custom Message");
    }
}
```

You can throw an exception from anywhere in your code, not only in the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Never throw `Throwable` instance.  The `Throwable` class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions.

For exception, Throw  `Exception` or `RuntimeException`  (for difference see java tutorial. link is given below)

Throw `Error`for serious problems. Errors should not be caught or handled (except in the rarest of cases)

> An `Error` is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions.

See [Java Tutorial for exception for more details and explanations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)